# Tensorflow: InvalidArgumentError: Expected image (JPEG, PNG, or GIF), got empty file

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I am a beginer. When I learned the tensorflow's programmer's guide, I tried to define a dataset_input_fn function used for 'estimator'. I got a wierd error for me, which shows:

> INFO:tensorflow:Using default config.
>
> INFO:tensorflow:Using config: {'_model_dir': '/model',
>   '_tf_random_seed': None, '_save_summary_steps': 100,
>   '_save_checkpoints_steps': None, '_save_checkpoints_secs': 600,
>   '_session_config': None, '_keep_checkpoint_max': 5,
>   '_keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours': 10000, '_log_step_count_steps': 100,
>   '_service': None, '_cluster_spec':
>   , '_task_type': 'worker', '_task_id': 0,
>   '_global_id_in_cluster': 0, '_master': '', '_evaluation_master': '',
>   '_is_chief': True, '_num_ps_replicas': 0, '_num_worker_replicas': 1}
>
> INFO:tensorflow:Calling model_fn.
>
> INFO:tensorflow:Done calling model_fn.
>
> INFO:tensorflow:Create CheckpointSaverHook.
>
> INFO:tensorflow:Graph was finalized.
>
> 2018-03-12 10:22:14.699465: I
>   C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-win\M\windows\PY\36\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:140]
>   Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not
>   compiled to use: AVX2
>
> INFO:tensorflow:Running local_init_op.
>
> INFO:tensorflow:Done running local_init_op.
>
> 2018-03-12 10:22:15.913858: W
>   C:\tf_jenkins\workspace\rel-win\M\windows\PY\36\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:1202]
>   OP_REQUIRES failed at iterator_ops.cc:870 : Invalid argument: Expected
>   image (JPEG, PNG, or GIF), got empty file      [[Node: DecodeJpeg =
>   DecodeJpegacceptable_fraction=1, channels=0, dct_method="",
>   fancy_upscaling=true, ratio=1,
>   try_recover_truncated=false]]
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):    File
>   "F:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 1361, in _do_call
>       return fn(*args)    File "F:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 1340, in _run_fn
>       target_list, status, run_metadata)    File "F:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py",
>   line 516, in **exit**
>       c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
>
> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Expected
>   image (JPEG, PNG, or GIF), got empty file       [[Node: DecodeJpeg =
>   DecodeJpegacceptable_fraction=1, channels=0, dct_method="",
>   fancy_upscaling=true, ratio=1,
>   try_recover_truncated=false]]
>       [[Node: IteratorGetNext =
>   IteratorGetNextoutput_shapes=[[?,28,28,1], [?]],
>   output_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32],
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]
>   During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):    File "F:\Program
>   Files\JetBrains\PyCharm
>   2017.3.3\helpers\pydev\pydev_run_in_console.py", line 53, in run_file
>       pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script    File "F:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm
>   2017.3.3\helpers\pydev_pydev_imps_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
>       exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)    File "E:/Learning_process/semester2018_spring/deep_learning/meituan/MNIST/demo_cnn_mnist_meituan.py",
>   line 201, in 
>       tf.app.run(main)    File "F:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py",
>   line 126, in run
>       _sys.exit(main(argv))    File "E:/Learning_process/semester2018_spring/deep_learning/meituan/MNIST/demo_cnn_mnist_meituan.py",
>   line 195, in main
>       steps=50)    File "F:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py",
>   line 352, in train
>       loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)    File
>   "F:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py",
>   line 891, in _train_model
>       _, loss = mon_sess.run([estimator_spec.train_op, estimator_spec.loss])    File
>   "F:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py",
>   line 546, in run
>       run_metadata=run_metadata)    File "F:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py",
>   line 1022, in run
>       run_metadata=run_metadata)    File "F:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py",
>   line 1113, in run
>       raise six.reraise(*original_exc_info)    File "F:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 693, in reraise
>       raise value    File "F:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py",
>   line 1098, in run
>       return self._sess.run(*args, **kwargs)    File "F:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py",
>   line 1170, in run
>       run_metadata=run_metadata)    File "F:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\monitored_session.py",
>   line 950, in run
>       return self._sess.run(*args, **kwargs)    File "F:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 905, in run
>       run_metadata_ptr)    File "F:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 1137, in _run
>       feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)    File "F:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 1355, in _do_run
>       options, run_metadata)    File "F:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py",
>   line 1374, in _do_call
>       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message) tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Expected
>   image (JPEG, PNG, or GIF), got empty file       [[Node: DecodeJpeg =
>   DecodeJpegacceptable_fraction=1, channels=0, dct_method="",
>   fancy_upscaling=true, ratio=1,
>   try_recover_truncated=false]]
>       [[Node: IteratorGetNext =
>   IteratorGetNextoutput_shapes=[[?,28,28,1], [?]],
>   output_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32],
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]
>   PyDev console: using IPython 6.1.0

The code is as follows:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

# Imports
import numpy as np
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
# parser.add_argument("--batch_size", default=100, type=int, help='batch_size')
# parser.add_argument("--train_steps", default=1000, type=int, help="train_steps")
parser.add_argument("--model_dir", default='/model', type=str, help='model_dir')
parser.add_argument("--data_dir", default='', type=str, help="data_dir")


def cnn_model(features, labels, mode):
    """

    :param features:
    :param labels:
    :param mode:
    :return:
    """

    # input
    input_layer = tf.reshape(features['image'], [-1, 28, 28, 1])

    conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=input_layer,
                             filters = 32,
                             kernel_size=[5, 5],
                             padding='same',
                             activation=tf.nn.relu)

    pool1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv1,
                                    pool_size=[2, 2],
                                    strides=2)

    conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=pool1,
                             filters=64,
                             kernel_size=[5, 5],
                             padding='same',
                             activation=tf.nn.relu)

    pool2 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv2,
                                    pool_size=[2, 2],
                                    strides=2)

    pool_flat = tf.reshape(pool2, [-1, 7 * 7 * 64])

    dense = tf.layers.dense(inputs=pool_flat,
                            units=1024,
                            activation=tf.nn.relu)

    dropout = tf.layers.dropout(inputs=dense,
                                rate=0.4,
                                training=mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN)

    logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dropout,
                             units=10,
                             activation=None)

    predictions = {
        'class_ids': tf.argmax(logits, 1),
        'probabilities': tf.nn.softmax(logits, name='softmax_tensor')
    }
    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode,
                                          predictions=predictions)

    loss = tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy(labels=labels, logits=logits)

    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL:
        eval_metric_ops = {
            'accuracy': tf.metrics.accuracy(labels=labels,
                                            predictions=tf.argmax(logits, 1))
        }
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode,
                                          loss=loss,
                                          eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops)

    # train
    assert mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001)
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss=loss,
                                  global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode,
                                      loss=loss,
                                      train_op=train_op)


def dataset_input_fn(filenames):
    """

    :param filenames: tfrecord file's path
    :return:
    """
    # filenames = ['train.tfrecords', 'test.tfrecords']
    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames)

    def _parse(record):
        features = {"image": tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string, default_value=""),
                    "label": tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.int64, default_value=0)}
        parsed = tf.parse_single_example(record, features)

        image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(parsed["image"])
        image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
        # image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, tf.float32)
        image = tf.reshape(image, [28, 28, 1])
        # image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
        # image = tf.decode_raw(features['image'], tf.float64)
        label = tf.cast(parsed['label'], tf.int32)
        return {'image': image}, label

    dataset = dataset.map(_parse)
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=10000)
    dataset = dataset.batch(100)
    dataset = dataset.repeat(1)

    iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
    features, labels = iterator.get_next()
    # features = tf.cast(features, tf.float32)
    return features, labels


def main(argv):
    """

    :param argv:
    :return:
    """
    args = parser.parse_args(argv[1:])
    train_path = ['train.tfrecords']
    test_path = ['test.tfrecords']

    print("\ndata has been loaded as 'train_x' and 'train_y'\n")

    classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=cnn_model,
                                        model_dir=args.model_dir)

    classifier.train(
        input_fn=lambda: dataset_input_fn(train_path),
        steps=50)

    print("\ntraining process is done\n")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.app.run(main)
```

Answer (score 4):

At least one example isn't an image.

You can check the datatype before feeding the image to the Neural Network.

I'm doing it with the library imghdr:

## Code:

```
import imghdr
import os

l_FileNames = os.listdir("images_path")

for image in l_FileNames:
    if not imghdr.what(image) == "png":
        l_FileNames.remove(image)
```

Comment: Well, today I found something uglier than camelCase in Python, mixing_snake_case_with_PascalCase in Python. I can already think of one think even worse, but I'll refrain. Jokes aside, you should just name your variable file_names or just filenames. Also you are modifying a list while iterating over it, which is something you should never do.

Comment: Better would be `filenames = [filename for filename in filenames if imghdr.what(filename) == "png"]

Comment: Even nicer: ```filenames = [filename for filename in glob.glob(directory, recursive=True) if imghdr.what(filename) in ("png","jpeg")]```

Answer (score 2):

The error seems to be that in some of your examples, there is no actual image.

Basically, when you call `image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(parsed["image"])`, `parsed["image"]` is an empty tensor.